# Definite Integral over the Gamma Function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, gamma-function

Do we have any methods for evaluating $$\int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{\Gamma(s)} \,ds$$?
I thought about perhaps rewriting as $$\int_1^{\infty} \frac{\Gamma(1-s)}{\Gamma(1-s) \Gamma(s)} \,ds$$

$$=\frac{1}{\pi} \int_1^{\infty} \Gamma(1-s) \sin(\pi s) \,ds $$

But I'm not too sure if this is all that useful. Thoughts?

Comment: Maybe use the integral definition for the gamma function on the last line? I mean, what makes you so certain that a closed form exists?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frans%C3%A9n%E2%80%93Robinson_constant

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{1}^\infty\Gamma(1-s)\sin(\pi s)ds=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^\infty e^{-x}\int_1^\infty \sin(\pi s)e^{-s\log(x)}dsdx=-\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\frac{ \frac{\pi}{x}}{\log^2(x)+\pi^2}dx=-\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x}}{x}\frac{dx}{\log^2(x)+\pi^2}$$ which looks similar to the [Fransen-Robinson Constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frans%C3%A9n%E2%80%93Robinson_constant) and has no known closed form.

Answer (score 3):

If we want to *evaluate* this integral, series expansion are not too bad.

Around $s=0$
$$ \frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}=s+\gamma  s^2+\left(\frac{\gamma ^2}{2}-\frac{\pi ^2}{12}\right) s^3+\frac{1}{12}
   s^4 \left(2 \gamma ^3-\gamma  \pi ^2-2 \psi ^{(2)}(1)\right)+O\left(s^5\right)\tag 1$$
Around $s=1$
$$ \frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}=1+\gamma  (s-1)+\left(\frac{\gamma ^2}{2}-\frac{\pi ^2}{12}\right)
   (s-1)^2+\frac{1}{12} (s-1)^3 \left(2 \gamma ^3-\gamma  \pi ^2-2 \psi
   ^{(2)}(1)\right)+\frac{(s-1)^4 \left(60 \gamma ^4-60 \gamma ^2 \pi ^2+\pi ^4-240
   \gamma  \psi ^{(2)}(1)\right)}{1440}+O\left((s-1)^5\right)\tag 2$$
As a function of the order of the expansions, we would get (in decimal representation)
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 n & (1) & (2) \\
 1 & 0.500000 & 0.711392 \\
 2 & 0.692405 & 0.492766 \\
 3 & 0.528436 & 0.503267 \\
 4 & 0.520035 & 0.536575 \\
 5 & 0.547792 & 0.543607 \\
 6 & 0.541763 & 0.542233 \\
 7 & 0.540561 & 0.541331 \\
 8 & 0.541363 & 0.541201 \\
 9 & 0.541246 & 0.541223 \\
 10 & 0.541227 & 0.541234
\end{array}
\right)$$ for an exact value $\approx 0.541236$.

Answer (score 0):

You can express in terms of [Nu Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NuFunction.html):

$\int_1^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{\Gamma(s)}~ds=\int_0^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{\Gamma(s+1)}~ds=\nu(1)$